# File URI Provider returns null only on Marshmallow 6.0

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to take a picture with a Kyrocera phone using the [official Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) as the basis.

The app crashes on line:

`Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider", photoFile);`

**The error message:**

> I/PhotosFragment: createImageFile()
>
> PhotosFragment:  mCurrentPhotoPath =
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_2017-02-08
>   10:38:49_-950025477.jpg
>
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>
> android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>
> at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
>
> at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
>
> at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
>
> at
>   com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.PhotoDetails.PhotosFragment.cameraIntent(PhotosFragment.java:303)

The Kyrocera phone specs:

- Model E6810
- Android 6.0.1
- Kernel Version 3.10.84-perf
- Security Software Version MDF v2.0 R4 Version  0.8

**In my Gradle file:**

```
 minSdkVersion 19
 targetSdkVersion 23
```

**Android Manifest**

```
  <!-- FILE MANAGERS -->
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**The Code:**

```
 private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {getString(R.string.camera_take_photo), getString(R.string.camera_from_gallery), "CANCEL"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean utilityResult = Utilities.checkPermission(getContext());
                if (items[item].equals(getString(R.string.camera_take_photo))) {
                    if (utilityResult) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    }
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
    private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPUTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            Log.i(TAG, "createImageFile() ");
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = Utilities.getDateTimeStamp();
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.i(TAG, "mCurrentPhotoPath = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }
```

**Any help?**

Comment: I do not know where this code resides in your app overall. Are you sure that `getContext()` is not returning `null` in your `getUriForFile()` call?

Comment: This code is in a Fragment @CommonsWare

Comment: Actually in Android N URI dont work in this case